# How to randomly select from list of lists

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of lists in python as follows:

```
a = [[1,1,2], [2,3,4], [5,5,5], [7,6,5], [1,5,6]]
```

for example, How would I at random select 3 lists out of the 6?

I tried numpy's `random.choice` but it does not work for lists.
Any suggestion?

Comment: show some codes what you have tried before.

Answer (score 1):

numpy's `random.choice` doesn't work on 2-d array, so one alternative is to use lenght of the array to get the random index of 2-d array and then get the elements from that random index. see below example.

```
import numpy as np

random_count = 3  # number of random elements to find
a = [[1,1,2], [2,3,4], [5,5,5], [7,6,5], [1,5,6]]  # 2-d data list
alist = np.array(a)  # convert 2-d data list to numpy array

random_numbers = np.random.choice(len(alist), random_count)  # fetch random index of 2-d array based on len

for item in random_numbers:  # iterate over random indexs
    print(alist[item])       # print random elememt through index
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the random library like this:

```py
a = [[1,1,2], [2,3,4], [5,5,5], [7,6,5], [1,5,6]]
import random
random.choices(a, k=3)
>>> [[1, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4], [7, 6, 5]]
```

You can read more about the random library at this official page https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html.